# Ruby Inspec - describe.one but one of the options requires two describe commands

Tags: ruby, inspec

I have a Ruby Inspec file that isn't very complex, but I can't figure out how to structure it properly. I basically need to check if `rsync` is *not installed* or disabled. To check if it's disabled, I run `systemctl is-active rsync` and `systemctl is-enabled rsync`. I then match the output to `inactive` and `disabled`, respectively.

```
control "my control" do
  title "title"
  desc "desc"

  describe.one do
    describe package('rsync') do
      it { should_not be_installed }
    end

    # These two should be treated as one option
    describe command('systemctl is-active rsync') do
      its('stdout') { should match "^inactive$" }
    end
    describe command('systemctl is-enabled rsync') do
      its('stdout') { should match "^disabled$" }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What about `only_if`? This should avoid the need for `describe.one` e.g. `only_if("Rsync is not installed") { package('rsync').installed? }`. Then you can describe your 2 commands which both would need to pass (which I believe is what you are asking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
control "my control" do
  title "title"
  desc "desc"

  if package('rsync').installed?
    # These two should be treated as one option
    describe command('systemctl is-active rsync') do
      its('stdout') { should match "^inactive$" }
    end
    describe command('systemctl is-enabled rsync') do
      its('stdout') { should match "^disabled$" }
    end
  end
end
```

or you should be able to do something like:

```
control "my control" do
  title "title"
  desc "desc"

  describe.one do
    describe package('rsync') do
      it { should_not be_installed }
    end

    describe 'rsync is inactive and disabled' do
      # These two should be treated as one option
      describe command('systemctl is-active rsync') do
        its('stdout') { should match "^inactive$" }
      end
      describe command('systemctl is-enabled rsync') do
        its('stdout') { should match "^disabled$" }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work. That was one of the first things I tried. The first one worked. I added an `else` clause to make sure it passes if it's not installed. Without the `else` the results show as no tests ran.